# Is it possible to get data contained in another document by id, when map function is running for some document in couchbase view?

Tags: view, couchbase

I have two kinds of documents in my couchbase bucket with keys like -

- product.id.1.main
- product.id.2.main
- product.id.3.main

and

- product.id.1.extended
- product.id.2.extended
- product.id.3.extended

I want to write a view for documents of first kind, such that when some conditions are matched for a document, I can emit the attributes contained in the documents of first kind as well as the document of second kind.

Something like -

```
function(doc, meta){ 
  if((meta.id).match("product.id.*.main") && doc.attribute1.match("value1"){
        var extendedDocId = replaceMainWithExtended(meta.id)
        emit(meta.id, doc.attribute1 +  getExtendedDoc(extendedDocId).extendedAttribute1 );
    }
}
```

I want to know how to implement this kind of function in couchbase views -

**getExtendedDoc(extendedDocId).extendedAttribute1**

Comment: I have a hunch it's easier to do this kind of thing with N1QL.

Comment: Which CB version are you using?

Comment: @deniswsrosa I am using v4.5. Anything that works on this version and above?

Comment: This Couchbase version is a little bit old (>3 years), and I'm afraid that this is not possible, your map function only can ever operate on the state of a single document, you cannot load other docs on the fly with it. If you upgrade to 5+ (current version is 6.6) you could easily implement this with N1QL